# Update a datatable with a string array as values

Tags: c#, database, string, datatable, arrays

I have a problem where I am trying to update a datatable's columns with values from a string array and then submit those updates to the database. I have debugged this, thinking there is an error, but no exception is thrown.

I have also set my adapater's select statement and connection so I can modify the data that is retuned when the event is fired initially.

Here is my code (the _updateParams string array contain the values I am trying to update the table and the database with).

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("SearchedRecord");
        using (OracleConnection oc = new OracleConnection(DBConnection))
        {
    try
            {
                oc.Open();

                OracleDataAdapter adap = new OracleDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM NEW_DATABASE", oc);
                adap.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "NEW_DATABASE");
                adap.Fill(ds, "NEW_DATABASE");

                OracleCommandBuilder bld = new OracleCommandBuilder(adap);

                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["NEW_DATABASE"];
                dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["ID"] };
                int key = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());

                DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.Rows.Find(key);

                dr.BeginEdit();
                for (int i = 0; i < _updateParams.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[0] = i.ToString();
                }
                dr.EndEdit();
                dr.AcceptChanges();
                dt.AcceptChanges();

                adap.Update(ds, "NEW_DATABASE");
                adap.UpdateCommand = bld.GetUpdateCommand();
                adap.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                adap.UpdateCommand.Transaction.Commit();
            }catch (Exception x)
            {
                x.Message.ToString();
            }
}
```

Comment: try wrapping your code around a Try{} catch{} and put some code to write out the error in the catch section ..

Comment: it is already in a try catch block

Comment: can't tell based on your code you may want to show all code that applies to the code that you posted otherwise others will think / recommend the same thing..what exception are you getting.???

Comment: I am not getting an exception though thats the thing.

Comment: would need to see the full code that you have up top starting with the method ..I think it would really help..thanks

Comment: ok i posted the code. thank you again

Comment: adap.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() ok so you are doing a "SELECT * FROM NEW_DATABASE 
1. why are you calling ExecuteNonQuery on a Select Statement and a Commit for a Select Statement.. you use ExecuteNonQuery for Update and Delete Commands.. where is the update query..?

Comment: i was under the impression that the commandbuilder took care of the updating for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all when you are adding the values of the string you are not actually doing it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _updateParams.Length; i++){
    dr[0] = i.ToString(); //You need to change this to _updateParams[i].ToString();
                          //And also concatenate it with "+" for example
}
```

And also, I'm not sure what language are you using (assume is some .Net based like C#), but should't this "dr[0]" be something like this "dr('YourColumName')", so in the end your code should look something like this:

```
String tmp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < _updateParams.Length; i++){
    tmp = tmp + _updateParams[i].ToString(); //The ToString is not needed if the _updateParams is a String array already
}

dr("YourColumnName") = tmp;
```

Hope it helps, but if not, please **remove your try catch statements to see the error** it's throwing and specify the language you are using.